# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"]; null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

i took this code to send an email. But i dont understand what that configurationManager does, and why it gives me the exception. Here is the full code:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.To.Add("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk");

    mail.Subject = "Test Email";

    string Body = "Welcome to CodeDigest.Com!!";

    mail.Body = Body;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"];

    smtp.Send(mail);
```

i also changed the last lines to this:
   smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

```
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

but it would still show a mistake, saying it didnt find IIS server..or something like that

Comment: What does the configuration file look like? Is there an `SMTP` value in the `appSettings` section?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use AppSettings an the ConfigurationManager for SMTP configuration. The preferred way is to [configure SMTP](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) through the `<mailSettings>` section in web.config. For example, the configuration for a small website could look like this:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="info@example.com">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="false">
     </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

This will allow you to new up an `SmtpClient` and just send the message without further configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) provides access to configuration files for client applications.

I guess the reason of the error is that the config file of your application does not have a SMTP key in the application settings section.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SMTP" value="..." />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: what should go inside the value=" "?

Comment: wwhat is an smtp server is it , yahoo.com?

Comment: [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is a protocol. I guess you can obtain its configurations from your network administrator.

Comment: isnt there any choice i could use a different code or a different algorithm..to send out email?... cause i dont even know what the smtp host is and what setting it should receive

Comment: @Dmitry: I have no solid idea about it. However, I have posted a question for it: [C#: What are the available methods for providing mailing services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949234/c-what-are-the-available-methods-for-providing-mailing-services)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there is no such SMTP configuration in the config file. I think you'd better check your `web.config`. And to make your application stronger, you need to add a default host in case of the config file is incorrect.

```
string defaultHost = "www.foo.com";
smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"] ?? defaultHost;
```

Comment: I doubt if this 'defaulthost' makes it stronger or weaker. I personaly prefer a real error insted of this kind of hard to trace fallbacks. Also if your defaulthost changes you need to redeploy

Comment: @Pleun: You are also correct. It really depends (on the requirement). Sometimes users want it work(just work, no care about the host), a default host is safer. But on the other hand, if users allow only one host, then we'd better throw exceptions. Thanks for your great advice!